# Python removing extra special unicode characters

Tags: python, unicode, special-characters, nltk, text-processing

I'm working with some text in python, it's already in unicode format internally but I would like to get rid of some special characters and replace them with more standard versions.

I currently have a line that looks like this, but it's getting ever more complex and I see it will eventually bring more trouble.

```
tmp = infile.lower().replace(u"\u2018", "'").replace(u"\u2019", "'").replace(u"\u2013", "").replace(u"\u2026", "")
```

for example the u\2018 and \u2019 are [left](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2018/index.htm) and [right](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm) single quotes. Those are somewhat acceptable but for this type of text processing I don't think they are needed.

Things like [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) u\2013 EN DASH and [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm) HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS are definitely not needed.

Is there a way to remove those quotation marks and use simple standard quotes that won't break text processing 'with nltk' and remove things like those EN DASH, HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS without making such a monster call like I see starting to rear it's head in the sample code above?

Comment: how do you get this text ? did you `decode()` it ? do you see this code when you use `print()` ?

Answer (score 7):

If your text is in English and you want to clean it up in a human-readable way, use the third-party module [`unidecode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode). It replaces a wide range of characters with their nearest ascii look-alike. Just apply `unidecode.unidecode()` to any string to make the substitutions:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
clean = unidecode(u'Some text: \u2018\u2019\u2013\u03a9')
```

Answer (score 1):

The unified solution would be using a predefined dict of replacement pairs. Such a dict can be easily extended(modified). 
The solution using `re.complile` and `re.sub` functions:

```
import re

d = {
    u"\u2018" : "'", u"\u2019" : "'", u"\u2013" : "", u"\u2026" : ""
}

pattern = re.compile(r'(' + '|'.join(re.escape(k) for k in d.keys()) + ')')
replaced = pattern.sub(lambda c: d[c.group()], infile.lower())
```

Comment: Make this approach more robust by escaping the keys in `d` with `re.escape()` before compiling the pattern. Otherwise, for example, adding the entry `".": ""` to `d` will delete the entire input.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this kind of characters "normalisation" you may consider implementing a **codec** for the [Codec registry](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html).

The implementation is similar as the one proposed by @RomanPerekhrest with a table of substitution characters.

#### Implementing a codec

Import the `codecs` module, give a name to your codec (avoid existing names).
Create the **encoding** table (the one you'll use when you do `u"something".encode(...)`:

```
import codecs

NAME = "normalize"

_ENCODING_TABLE = {
    u'\u2002': u' ',
    u'\u2003': u' ',
    u'\u2004': u' ',
    u'\u2005': u' ',
    u'\u2006': u' ',
    u'\u2010': u'-',
    u'\u2011': u'-',
    u'\u2012': u'-',
    u'\u2013': u'-',
    u'\u2014': u'-',
    u'\u2015': u'-',
    u'\u2018': u"'",
    u'\u2019': u"'",
    u'\u201a': u"'",
    u'\u201b': u"'",
    u'\u201c': u'"',
    u'\u201d': u'"',
    u'\u201e': u'"',
    u'\u201f': u'"',
    }
```

The table above can "normalize" spaces, hyphens, quotation marks.
This is where normalisation rules go…

Then, implement the function used to normalize your string:

```
def normalize_encode(input, errors='strict'):
    output = u''
    for char in input:
        output += _ENCODING_TABLE.get(char, char)
    return output, len(input)
```

You can also implement the decoding, but you need to reverse the `_ENCODING_TABLE`,
the best practice is to prepare the reversed table and fill the missing characters later.

```
_DECODING_TABLE = {v: k for k, v in _ENCODING_TABLE.items()}
# missing characters...

def normalize_decode(input, errors='strict'):
    output = u''
    for char in input:
        output += _DECODING_TABLE.get(char, char)
    return output, len(input)
```

Now, everything is ready, you can implements the **codec** protocol:

```
class Codec(codecs.Codec):
    def encode(self, input, errors='strict'):
        return normalize_encode(input, errors)

    def decode(self, input, errors='strict'):
        return normalize_decode(input, errors)


class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
    def encode(self, input, final=False):
        assert self.errors == 'strict'
        return normalize_encode(input, self.errors)[0]


class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
    def decode(self, input, final=False):
        assert self.errors == 'strict'
        return normalize_decode(input, self.errors)[0]


class StreamWriter(Codec, codecs.StreamWriter):
    pass


class StreamReader(Codec, codecs.StreamReader):
    pass


def getregentry():
    return codecs.CodecInfo(name=NAME,
                            encode=normalize_encode,
                            decode=normalize_decode,
                            incrementalencoder=IncrementalEncoder,
                            incrementaldecoder=IncrementalDecoder,
                            streamreader=StreamReader,
                            streamwriter=StreamWriter)
```

How to register the newly created codec?

If you have several normalisation codecs, the best practice is to gather
them in the `__init__.py` file of a dedicated package
(for instance: `my_app.encodings`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs

import normalize


def search_function(encoding):
    if encoding == normalize.NAME:
        return normalize.getregentry()
    return None


# Register the search_function in the Python codec registry
codecs.register(search_function)
```

Whenever you need your codec, you write:

```
import my_app.encodings

normalize = my_app.encodings.normalize.NAME

def my_function():
    normalized = my_string.encode(normalize)
```

Comment: Overkill.  Use [translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

Comment: Reinventing the wheel. Use `unidecode` instead of an ad hoc substitution table.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in string method [translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).  It takes a dictionary of Unicode ordinals as keys and translates to the values, which can be Unicode ordinals, strings or None.  The value None deletes characters:

```
sample = '\u2018hello\u2019\u2013there\u2026'
print(sample)
replacements = { 0x2018 : "'",
                 0x2019 : "'",
                 0x2013 : '-',
                 0x2026 : '...' }
print(sample.translate(replacements))
```

Output:

```
‘hello’–there…
'hello'-there...
```

Answer (score 0):

[re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) will do it too:

```
import re
tmp = re.sub(u'\u2019|\u2018', '\'', infile.lower())
tmp = re.sub(u'\u2013|\u2026', '', tmp)
```