# Special Unicode Characters are not removed in Python 3

Tags: python, regex, string, unicode

I have a `keys` list including words. When I make this command:

```
for key in keys:
  print(key)
```

I get normal output in terminal.

[image]

but when I print the entire list using `print(keys)`, I get this output:

[image]

I have tried using `key.replace("\u202c", '')`, `key.replace("\\u202c", '')`, `re.sub(u'\u202c', '', key)` but none solved the problem.
I also tried the solutions here, but none of them worked either:

[Replacing a unicode character in a string in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635344/replacing-a-unicode-character-in-a-string-in-python-3)

[Removing unicode \u2026 like characters in a string in python2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321138/removing-unicode-u2026-like-characters-in-a-string-in-python2-7)

[Python removing extra special unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690460/python-removing-extra-special-unicode-characters)

[How can I remove non-ASCII characters but leave periods and spaces using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689795/how-can-i-remove-non-ascii-characters-but-leave-periods-and-spaces-using-python)

I scraped this from Google Trends using Beautiful Soup and retrieved text from `get_text()`
Also in the page source of Google Trends Page, the words are listed as follows:

[image] When I pasted the text here directly from the page source, the text pasted without these unusual symbols.‬‬

Comment: @OferSadan I just tried this, getting the same output as in the question.

Comment: Do a `sub(r'\p{Block=General_Punctuation}+','')` on each item in the list after it is generated. Or, you can use the range `[\u2000-\u206F]+` which is the _block_. See https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+2000

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Punctuation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just strip out the characters using `strip`.

```
>>> keys=['\u202cABCD', '\u202cXYZ\u202c']
>>> for key in keys:
...     print(key)
... 
ABCD
XYZ‬
>>> newkeys=[key.strip('\u202c') for key in keys]
>>> print(keys)
['\u202cABCD', '\u202cXYZ\u202c']
>>> print(newkeys)
['ABCD', 'XYZ']
>>>
```

Tried 1 of your methods, it does work for me:

```
>>> keys
['\u202cABCD', '\u202cXYZ\u202c']
>>> newkeys=[]
>>> for key in keys:
...     newkeys += [key.replace('\u202c', '')]
... 
>>> newkeys
['ABCD', 'XYZ']
>>>
```

Comment: This worked out for me! Any insights on why the methods I tried earlier didn't work?

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja I tried 1 of your methods, it does work for me in python3